# How to Sync my api call in Background using service worker in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

im stuck in calling api in backgruond by using React js Service worker Even i gone through all the Online resources none of them helped me please help me to get rid of it

```html
 getResponse = e => {
    fetch(
      "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR"
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Fetching Data");
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        throw new Error("Request failed.");
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ respo: data });

        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.respo);
      });
  };
```

i need to throw getresponse  function to my BackGround call

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, sorry :) What is the problem?